# Is it possible to make the maximum icon zoom in plank more than 200%?

Tags: plank

I would like to make the icon zoom in plank more than 200% so that I can have many small icons but then have them greatly enlarged when I scroll over them, to emulate the behaviour of the OSX dock. I have tried modifying the settings using the dconf editor but this results in no change in the dock.